# Can the main conflict be the inner conflict?

Tags: plot, conflict

I've recently been having trouble with developing plots. The plots I created seemed heavily sequential. No matter how many twists or complications I put in, they always seemed dry, proceeding from one problem to the next.

I believe I have discovered a way to fix this: by making *sure*, from the beginning, that my conflict is linked to the theme, or message, of my novel. In addition, I link the main character to the theme. This seems to be working, and has the added benefit of acting as a safeguard against accidental preaching of said theme.

HOWEVER, it appears that this method is prone to making the hero's inner conflict (what I think of as conflicting sides within the protagonist) be the MAIN conflict (the main problem in the story). The main conflict *is* the inner conflict.

**Is this okay?** This doesn't strike me as much of a problem, but being an aspiring author, I want to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's totally okay, and makes for a nice vehicle of the theme (the plot itself is the deepest, subtlest and thus most effective means of making argument, as opposed to say the dialogue/opinions of your characters).

But you shouldn't worry about whether or not it's arbitrarily "okay". Hesitation holds new writers back, and one of the quickest ways to develop as a writer (and maybe even innovate your form) is to discard your fear of "breaking the rules". Could Joyce have written *Ulysses* if he were afraid of doing something "wrong" like this? Could Cortázar have written *Rayuela*?

My advice (and this is advice given to scientists and mathematicians, too): trust yourself. You are a human; you have experiences that others can empathize with, and you have messages you wish to send. If you have a new idea for how to tell a story that hasn't been done before, you should be all the more excited to try it out first.

Good luck!

EDIT

Popular example of a novel driven by a character's inner conflict: *Moby Dick*. If it worked for Melville, it can work for you!

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the genre and what you're trying to achieve, but it's certainly an accepted literary tool. The good ol' Man vs Self conflict.

It'll almost certainly result in a character-driven novel, but there's nothing wrong with character-driven novels!